# Css position divs gives unexpected result

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I'm making portfolio website. After position fixed half transparent gradient animation and image the `margin` of images element don't work. When creating element `#images` i wanted to be under the text 10vh. I expected the image to be under text element. But the sample image is on the top and move the gradient down. Why and how to  put the `#images` under the text?

https://codepen.io/abooo/pen/erQWBQ?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

```
 *{margin:0;padding:0;}
html { 
   height:100%;
   width:100%;  
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
div#overlay{
    position:fixed;
    opacity:0.5;
    background: linear-gradient(224deg, #a18cd1, #fbc2eb, #fbc2eb, #a6c1ee, #f6d365, #fda085, #84fab0, #8fd3f4, #a6c0fe, #f68084, #fccb90, #d57eeb, #e0c3fc, #8ec5fc, #f093fb, #f5576c, #4facfe, #00f2fe, #43e97b, #38f9d7, #30cfd0, #330867, #667eea, #764ba2, #fddb92, #d1fdff, #00c6fb, #005bea, #b721ff, #21d4fd, #d558c8, #24d292, #09203f, #537895);
background-size: 6800% 6800%;
height:100%;
width:100%;
-webkit-animation: GardientOverlay 200 ease infinite;
-moz-animation: GardientOverlay 200 ease infinite;
-o-animation: GardientOverlay 200s ease infinite;
animation: GardientOverlay 200s ease infinite;

}
@-webkit-keyframes GardientOverlay {
    0%{background-position:99% 0%}
    50%{background-position:2% 100%}
    100%{background-position:99% 0%}
}
@-moz-keyframes GardientOverlay {
    0%{background-position:99% 0%}
    50%{background-position:2% 100%}
    100%{background-position:99% 0%}
}
@-o-keyframes GardientOverlay {
    0%{background-position:99% 0%}
    50%{background-position:2% 100%}
    100%{background-position:99% 0%}
}
@keyframes GardientOverlay { 
    0%{background-position:99% 0%}
    50%{background-position:2% 100%}
    100%{background-position:99% 0%}
}

div#text{
font-size:calc(6vh + 6vw);
}
div#containerText{
    padding:1vw;
    opacity:0.7;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:10;
position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

text-align:center;
  display:flex;
    align-items: center; /* Vertical center alignment */
    justify-content: center;
}
.text{
    left:0;
    width:100vw;
    top:100vh;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    padding:calc(1vh + 1vw);
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size:2vmax;
}
div#images{
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
}
div#images img{
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='overlay'></div>
        <div id='images'>
            <img src='https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg' alt='gallery'/>
        </div>
        <div id='containerText'>
              <div id='text'>Hi!</div>
        </div>
        <div class='text'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas faucibus mattis quam sit amet sollicitudin. Vivamus quis ullamcorper velit. Phasellus vitae quam id libero tempus tempor in in velit. Maecenas at arcu nec felis feugiat mollis. Quisque et velit eu enim ullamcorper vestibulum eu convallis justo. Donec scelerisque purus ipsum, ut consequat enim scelerisque vitae. Aliquam dignissim massa non dolor sollicitudin, eleifend aliquam urna commodo. Pellentesque ut tristique erat. Sed non nisl ac odio consectetur tincidunt. Integer turpis sem, viverra et vulputate ut, dignissim id diam. Nullam venenatis, ante rhoncus tincidunt pulvinar, ex velit blandit nisi, ut laoreet ex odio vitae metus. Morbi arcu elit, congue a nisl vitae, euismod facilisis sapien. Donec gravida, lorem eu volutpat tristique, lectus erat pharetra justo, a aliquam massa quam tincidunt purus. Phasellus eu fringilla sapien. Quisque imperdiet magna sed sapien rutrum, quis mattis libero convallis. Vivamus non luctus leo.

        </div>          

    </body>
</html>
```

Try html and css above.